# jquery how to fetch html of the same classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hello People below is my code...

```
<font class="detDesc" >
    Uploaded 07-11&nbsp;2012, Size 105.79&nbsp;MiB, ULed by 
    <a class="detDesc" href="/somelink" title="somelink title">somelink</a>
</font>
```

Now i want to fetch only `Uploaded 07-11&nbsp;2012, Size 105.79&nbsp;MiB, ULed by`   how can i achieve this?as we can observe there are two element with the same class name `detDesc` ...
I know about taking in `different span or div element and then $(#span).html()` 
But 
`I cant change this HTMl as its a external api`....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this js :

```
var value = $('a.detDesc').parent().text();
var valx = $('a.detDesc').text();
var fval = value.replace(valx,'');//this is the value you want
alert(fval); //alert for test only
```